# I can't connect to my database via SSH

Tags: macos, ssh, intellij-idea

When I try to connect to my database via SSH on IntelliJ, I have the following error :
"Connection to @VPS failed.
[08S01] Communications link failure.
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server".
But, when I try from another computer, the connection is "Successful".
I'm on Macos

What can I do for resolve my problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution, the problem was in the hosts file, I had, "::1 localhost" and now I modified on "127.0.0.1 localhost"